# Compiling devIL Image Loader

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, terminal, devil

I am trying to compile the devIL image loader from my terminal, please tell me what I am doing wrong.

1. Downloaded devIL 1.7.8, and unzipped in my "Downloads" folder
2. Entered my Mac Terminal and typed, "**Downloads/devil-1.7.8/configure**", this seems to work fine.
3. Typed, "**make**" into my terminal which results in the following error:
        **error: invalid argument '-std=gnu99' not allowed with 'C++/ObjC++'**

Let me know if any additional information will be helpful.